# Python: how to shorten integers in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like the following

```
df 
        T
0  1573119508850
1  1573119511513
2  1573119516821
3  1573119520387
```

I would like to shorten the number and approximate them with an approximation like the following:

```
df 
        T
0  1573119509
1  1573119512
2  1573119517
3  1573119520
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need divide by `1000`, round and last convert to integers:

```
df['T'] = df['T'].div(1000).round().astype(int)
print (df)
            T
0  1573119509
1  1573119512
2  1573119517
3  1573119520
```

Comment: wouldn't `df['T']//1000` have the same effect?

Comment: @YaakovBressler - no, because not rounding -  `0    1573119508
1    1573119511
2    1573119516
3    1573119520
Name: T, dtype: int64`